# How to access to a primitives of random selected turtle/agentset - general way - NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I am learning NetLogo and I am confused by syntax. 
For example, if I create friend for one patch and I want to one of the patch count/access to their neighbors and the neighbors of it friend, what is general way to do it?
For example this line is working:

```
set sum-num sum [number] of neighbors + sum [ [number] of neighbors ] of friend
```

But this is not, why?

```
set sum-num count neighbors with [number = 1]  + (count [neighbors with [sum-num = 1]] of friend)
```

In my test example, this two lines should give the same result.

Test code of example for the easier understanding:

```
patches-own [friend number sum-num]


to setup
  ca
  ask one-of patches [
   set friend one-of patches
   set pcolor green
    ask friend [set pcolor red]
  ]

 ask patches [
    set number random 2
    set plabel number
  ]

end

to go
  ask patches with [pcolor = green][
    ;set sum-num sum [number] of neighbors + sum [ [number] of neighbors ] of friend
    set sum-num count neighbors with [number = 1]  + (count [neighbors with [sum-num = 1]] of friend)
    set plabel sum-num

  ]

end
```

If someone can point me to some article/part of documentation (which I clearly don't see) or explain general way how to access random agent/agentset, I would appreciate.:) I always lost some time on this kind of situation. It's clear to me that something I missed.
I know how to access `ask`, but in this type of situation the ask is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need parenthesis in the second example. It's assigning sum-num first, then adding the second half of the equation.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I didn't get the error or something, just the first sum :/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing:

```
count [neighbors with [sum-num = 1]] of friend
```

and wondering whether NetLogo will parse it the way you intended (or whether you need to add parentheses), I'd suggest writing:

```
[count neighbors with [sum-num = 1]] of friend
```

removing any possible ambiguity.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I didn't get the error or something, just the first sum (count neighbors with [number = 1]  )